# How can I get keys and values from a hash reference?

Tags: perl

```
my $data = shift;
warn Dumper $data;    
$VAR1 = {

    'sessid' => '3c18e794b31c46eb0c....',
    'code' => '0',
    'message' => 'Authentication succeeded'

};
```

I want to fetch the keys and values.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to StackExchange.

You should read up on the functions [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) (which iterates over all key/value pairs), [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) (which returns an array of all keys) and [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) (which... well you can guess it) in the `perldoc` page called [`perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html). Example:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each %{ $data }) {
  print "key: $key; value: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Also `%$data`, which gives you a list of keys & values interleaved.